# Using Shared and Core modules besides Feature modules in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-module

In my Angular app, I follow [this](https://www.perfomatix.com/best-practices-in-angular-coding/) approach to build my architecture and added `shared.module.ts` file to the shared folder. I also use **lazy-loading** in my app, but at this step I am very confused regarding to the imports, declarations and exports that should be added to each modules. So, by looking the folder structure on [this](https://www.perfomatix.com/best-practices-in-angular-coding/) page (I also add `shared.module.ts` file to the shared folder) and keeping consideration lazy-loading, what should my modules's imports, declarations and exports, etc.? I also follow this approach as sjown below:

***App Module:*** In this module, we have to import the modules/packages which we will use throughout our system. Like: CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule etc. And we don't need to export these modules as it will be

***Core Module:*** In this module, we have to make components which will be used in almost every page of the system. Like: HeaderComponent, FooterCompoennt, AuthGaurds etc. And these components should be exported so that it will be available in other modules.

***Shared Module:*** In this module, we have to make the Services, Components, Pipes, and Directives which will be used in more than one component. Like: AlertDialogBox, HTTPService, etc.

***User Module (assume feature module):*** This is a featured module. It will have the components specific to a User Module. Here we can import Shared Module so that we can use AlertDialogBox and all.

On the other hand, I think I should add a `xxx-routing.module.ts` file for each module that is navigated. Is that true? Do I also have to add for shared module?

Comment: You need to create for every module an index which u will be able to access files from another modules in another module.
Routing you don't need to add I think, because I worked in different projects and the routing module it was only once declared.

Comment: Thanks but I use laz-loading. So, maybe there is no need to use routing in the shared module, but for the others I need. On the other hand I found [another](https://github.com/anihalaney/rwa-trivia/blob/part-7/src/app/routing/routing.module.ts) example, but I do not understand why it use `routing.module.ts` file. Because when usinhg lazy-loading, we just use this file in the feature modules, rather than root module. Am I wrong? Because it is not used in your example. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Shared Module and Core Module might not need the routing.module.ts. But it all depeneds on your requirement.

This github repo has a implemented bes practices which you might want to take a look to understand.
[https://github.com/DanWahlin/angular-architecture/tree/master/demos/src/app[enter](https://github.com/DanWahlin/angular-architecture/tree/master/demos/src/app%5Benter) link description here][1](https://github.com/DanWahlin/angular-architecture/tree/master/demos/src/app)

Comment: Thansk a lot. I think the example you gave use lazy-loading, is that true? On the other hand, I was working on [another](https://github.com/anihalaney/rwa-trivia/blob/part-7/src/app/routing/routing.module.ts) example, but I do not understand why it use `routing.module.ts` file. Because when usinhg lazy-loading, we just use this file in the feature modules, rather than root module. Am I wrong? Because it is not used in your example. Any idea?